how to pass a uri parameter in function app from logic app
I have created a function app which takes a URI parameter

then I have created a logic app, from the logic app I want to call the function app but not sure how to pass URI parameter here

I am not sure how to pass uri parameter from logic app while calling a function app

My function expects name parameter as shown below-


In order to pass this parameter in Call an Azure function action, you need to add Queries from Advanced parameters.



Then pass the parameter name and value as shown below.


This will give you expected result.



Sorry but that's  the query parameter, I am looking for URI parameter

@shrikant Can you share some example

I have to call below URL from the logic app   https://hostname/api/clubs/{userid}

@shrikant with the help of parameters you can pass the uri paramters like hostname/api/clubs/@{parameters('userId')}

@IkhtesamAfrin The OP may be able to work around the problem using parameters, but it can be difficult when the URI is stored in a function connection object rather than in the action definition. This will be particularly hard if the desired URI value is coming from the output of a previous action and not a parameter.

You can select Advanced parameters = Queries like this:


I've been struggling with this exact problem, and I don't have a completely acceptable solution yet. But I do have some observations and some possible workarounds worth considering.
First, one thing to note is that the nature of this problem varies a little bit depending on if you are using a consumption logic app or a standard logic app. It's a bit easier for consumption LAs because they don't use a separate connection object for each function. Instead, the URI is embedded in the Azure Function action itself. As an example, here is the code view of an Azure function app with an ID parameter:
{
  "type": "Function",
  "description": "Function description",
  "inputs": {
    "functionApp": {
      "id": "/subscriptions/xxx/resourceGroups/yyy/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/ZZZ"
    },
    "method": "post",
    "uri": "https://zzz.azurewebsites.net/api/function/{encodeURIComponent(variables('id'))}",
    "body": {
      "name": "@body('Parse_data_from_JSON')?['app']?['name']",
      "version": "@{body('Parse_data_from_JSON')?['app']?['version']}"
    }
  }
}

Note that the uri value includes a URL-encoded version of the "id" flow variable. Due to limitations of the current logic app user interface, there is no way to enter that expression for the ID variable directly in the URI. However, I can go into the code view and directly add it there, and it seems to work.
When trying to do this in a standard logic app it gets more convoluted and, as far as I know, more limited. The URI of the Azure function is no longer included in directly the action definition. Instead, the action definition references a function connection object, and that connection object contains the URI. For example, here is a connection object that I have associated with an Azure function action:
{
    "functionConnections": {
        "azureFunctionOperation": {
            "authentication": {
                "name": "Code",
                "type": "QueryString",
                "value": "@appsetting('azureFunctionOperation_functionAppKey')"
            },
            "displayName": "My Function Application",
            "function": {
                "id": "/subscriptions/xxx/resourceGroups/yyy/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/zzz/functions/MyFunc"
            },
            "triggerUrl": "https://zzz.azurewebsites.net/api/myFunc/1234"
        }
}

Here you can see that the triggerUrl is where you would want to insert your URL parameter reference. But I'm not 100% sure if it is possible to reference an output from a previous flow action, a flow variable, etc. It is also harder to directly edit the connection objects. I know if you are working in a local development environment you can edit the connections.json file and publish it with your logic app, but this can be a bit tricker than just editing the action in a consumption logic app.
With all that said, I did want to offer a bit of a workaround that takes some additional work up front but seems to be a little more capable. The workaround approach I am currently working through is by defining a Swagger/OpenAPI specification for my Azure Function app's API endpoints. When I want to call the function, I use the HTTP + Swagger action instead of the Azure function action. This action recognizes all inputs defined in the OpenAPI specification including URI parameters, query parameters, and request body contents. All of those inputs are associated with an input entry field in the logic app's flow designer.
In the end, the creation of an OpenAPI definition of my functions' API endpoints does add some amount of work. But the result is that the function's API is more explicitly defined, more easily consumed in logic apps, more easily exposed through Azure API Management, etc. And it seems to suffer from none of the limitations you've noted when using the Azure Function action.
